# jquery plugin to show multiple elapsed time timers on a page?

Tags: jquery, plugins, timer

I need to show on a page multiple -time zone independent- elapsed time timers.
I'd like to have something similar to what is shown on the NASA mission pages, where they show the mission time (e.g. http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/main/index.html).

I'd like to use a jquery plugin for that, so I'd like you to advice me on the most appropriate plugins for the job.

The perfect plugin would take an input independent of the client time,such as the elapsed seconds at the page download time, and start counting from that moment.

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) might be able to serve that purpose.

Comment: thanks, I've downloaded and implemented in no time. I didn't see the "since" option when I discovered it from google some time ago :)
I'd like to know if there is an alternative that is less cpu intensive, since I might have several timers on a page. 
but until then, that's my choiche, thanks.